# How to detect USB insertion and log current user

Tags: linux, usb, python, users, udev

I need to write a script that logs what user inserted what USB, and sends information to a server. I created a udev rule that runs a python script when it detects a USB insertion. The script writes to log file information about inserted USB and sends this info to a server. The problem is, it seems the script is run as root, not as current user, since id command return uid=0(root). Is it possible to get currently logged in user from a udev-run script, and if not, are there alternatives that can do it?

Comment: How would you possibly do this?  What if alice, bob, and steve are all logged in when a USB device is connected?  To whom whould the log assign the blame?

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, you can't do this in any sane way, because:

- You might have multiple users logged in at the same time.  You then could log everyone, but that still isn't reliable because of the second issue.
- User names don't reliably translate to who is actually physically present at the system.

If you're *really* set on doing this, log the output of the `who` command alongside the USB info.  That will give you a list of who all has active logins, on what terminal, from where, and when they logged in.  This works around the first issue, but not the second one (and you *can't* work around the second one without some hardware being involved.

Alternatively, look into [usbguard](https://usbguard.github.io/), set it up to require authorization for everything, and then log who authorizes the device (which *should* be the person who plugged it in, but there's no way to guarantee this).

Comment: While I understand what you are saying it is exactly what happens when you plugin in an USB storage device in Linux. It  gets automatically mounted under `/var/run/media/<USERNAME>/` for the specific user which is logged in.